# Why do selected vertices create two faces instead of one?

Tags: bezier-curves, faces

I'm starting with a Bezier curve:

[image]

I convert it to a mesh, then duplicate it and mirror the duplicate on the X axis, then join the two meshes. Then I duplicate and mirror again, now on the Y axis, and join the two halves, and I get this:
[image]

From there, in the Edit Mode, I hit 'F' to create a face and I get half a face:
[image]
If I hit 'F' a second time, it makes a second face:
[image]
My guess is that I'm doing something wrong when I join the different sections together so somehow it doesn't look like one long mesh. I've also done this where I've created the entire curve, all 4 quarters joined together, then extruded it along the Z-axis so it became a prism. I joined the faces on one end of the prism and still got two faces.

What am I doing wrong that all the vertices in the joined shape do not act like one set of vertices, but, instead, act as two sets? And, if there's no way to make it produce one face, what do I need to do to join the two faces into one? (I'm also open to doing more of this operation before I convert the curve to a mesh, but last I checked, there was no way to join two curves.)

Link to file with the original Bezier curve and the mesh just before I try to add the face is here: [image]

Comment: could you please share your object, the step just before you fill? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: When asking what you need to do to join the two faces into one, usually you just have to hit F once again while both faces are selected. If that doesn't work, there is definitely something wrong with your mesh and it would be best to upload your file as @moonboots suggested.

Comment: By the way: you duplicate and mirror it on the X axis, then join the two meshes, then duplicate and mirror it again on the Y axis and join it? I would suggest you take the first quadrant, add a _Mirror_ modifier to it, enable X and Y axis, make sure you have the _Merge_ option enabled and then apply the modifier.

Comment: @moonbots: Added it at the end of the question.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann When I mirror it and enable both X and Y, I get overlaps or bad positioning. I'm not clear where to put the origin so when I mirror it, I get the shape I need.

Comment: @Tango The origin needs to be exactly where you want it to mirror in X and Y direction. So the X coordinate has to be the one of the right vertex and for the Y coordinate you need the one of the left vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you zoom in close to your full curve, it is visible that the vertices are separate. Either do what @GordonBrinkman said on the original curve or do this:

Press `M` > `Merge By Distance` (After selecting all by pressing `A`) and then press `F` to fill, it will join the separate vertices and solve your problem:

[image]